# documentquery.SelectorAll to fill a textbox with CSS value using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a textbox whose CSS selector value is as follows:

```css
tr.panel-component:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(3) > jhi-alpha-numeric:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > input:nth-child(1)
```

I am using JS to fill up this textbox using this code, but I am not able to execute it.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("[tr.panel-component:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(3) > jhi-alpha-numeric:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > input:nth-child(1)]")   .forEach(o => {
    if (o.value && !isNaN(o.value) && o.value < 0.9) o.value = `NON REACTIVE(${o.value})`;   });
```

Please guide me where I am going on.
Thank you in advance

Comment: What goes wrong? Error in console? Hard for us to guess the problem

Comment: Hello, it goes wrong in the sense that nothing gets filled up. It remains as it is. I doubt the code is wrong.

Comment: Well did you debug? `var elems = document.querySelectorAll("[tr.panel-component:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(3) > jhi-alpha-numeric:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > input:nth-child(1)]"); console.log(elems.length); 
elems.forEach( elem => {
  const isCheck = o.value && !isNaN(o.value) && o.value < 0.9;
  console.log( elem.value, isCheck); 
  if(isCheck) o.value = \`NON REACTIVE(${o.value})\`;
});`

Comment: If I select document.querySelectorAll("[id="class name"]")... the code executes to fill up the textbox  correctly, but when I use the CSS selector in place of id="class name", it doesn't happen, why is that?

Comment: Hard to guess why the selector does not work when we have no clue what the html is.

Comment: You have a `<jhi-alpha-numeric>` element?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, what exactly should I let u know? I am not a computer expert, I am just trying with the codes

Comment: We can not guess why a selector does not work without html

Comment: Actually I see it now....

Comment: `[tr.panel` <-- You have a `[` and a closing `]` which is saying it is an attribute selector. The string you have to start out the post is how it should look.

Comment: Well putting in a simple way, I have this CSS selector value in the question I had put up, I want to use documentquery.SelectorAll to fill this CSS selector with a value APPLE. What should be the code for this?

Comment: Delete the leading `[` and trialing `]`

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the leading [ and trailing ] for the querySelectorAll is the solution. Thank you to epascarello.